# What are "transactions and earnings" within the IRA?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, ira

I'm a European citizen who needs, for professional reasons, to understand in broad terms how the IRA works.

I read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Individual_retirement_account), and there is written that "all transactions and earnings within the IRA have no tax impact".

What is a "transaction within IRA"? It's like when the IRA buys government bonds? And what does it mean "have no tax impact"? Does it mean that the coupon payouts are tax-exempt?

Comment: I can move investments around within an IRA with no taxable consequences. For example, open a position in a new fund, move money from stock to bond funds, etc. All things that will show up as 'transactions' on the IRA statement, but if they are all in my IRA they are all fine. If you hold individual bonds in an IRA, then yes, any income they generate that stays within the IRA would remain tax exempt until withdrawn from the IRA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of IRA as a brokerage account with tax events only happening when money flows *into* the account or *out of* the account, bu nothing *within* the account triggers any tax events.

This is similar to retirement/pension vehicles you surely have in your own country.

Comment: So I decide which investments to pursue? And if I invest all my money in the shares of a company that goes bankrupt the day before I retire, I'm left with no pension?

Comment: @robertspierre yes, IRAs are self-directed. Pensions are becoming very rare in the US, most retirement plans are defined contributions with varying levels of flexibility for participants to decide on their own investment mix.

Comment: @robertspierre+ although if you work (legally) in the US, you will _also_ pay into the government-run retirement program Social Security, with very few exceptions (mostly if you work for a state or local government agency that has a defined-benefit pension at least as good actuarially as SS), and assuming you work at least 10 years, at age 62 or higher you get 'guaranteed' SS benefits based on your earnings history plus inflation. SS (OASI) benefits _may_ be partly or wholly tax-free depending on how much other income you have.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 that's on top of the IRA? Your point is that if I get an IRA ,invest all my money in company's A shares, and company A goes bankrupt the day before I  retire, I would still get social security the day after?

Comment: Yes, social security is a government funded safety net. It's not exactly a pension, but there is some correlation between contributions and the resulting defined benefit. But it's funded through taxes, not the contributions per se (in a sense that there's an actuary deficit built into the system).

Comment: @robertspierre: not exactly one day after; due to the large population (and money) involved SS has [a rather complicated schedule](https://blog.ssa.gov/what-day-of-the-month-do-i-get-my-social-security-payment/). But you cannot lose SS by any mistake you make, which was the point of your question. The 'primary' benefit computation _can_ vary about 25% depending on _when_ you claim (down to age 62 or up to age 70), but cannot be eliminated.

Comment: @robertspierre+la SS is funded by the dedicated tax (employer and employee each 6.2% of payroll up to 'wage base') which is _labelled_ contribution (the law is titled Federal Insurance _Contributions_ Act); there is no other subsidy. Medicare Part A is similarly funded by dedicated tax (1.45%x2 no limit, recently plus a highincome addon), but Part B mostly by general revenue and Part D by beneficiary premiums. SS and Part A (HI) trust funds are required to 'invest' in government bonds which pay lower rates than private sector, effectively a reverse subsidy.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 right, but the SS is funded by the current taxpayers. The person who contributes today will be paying money used for SS benefits of the current retirees, not their own. It's funded by dedicated taxes, but still - funded by taxes. And as you described, the actuary deficit is built in, so this is an essence a pyramid scheme and not a self-sufficient pension plan as private plans are (supposed to be, at least).

Comment: _mostly_ by current taxpayers yes, but the 'trust fund' (which is not the same as a private one, but _is_ dedicated) currently could fund over 2 years of benefits, and does cover the currently-small (but growing) cash gap, and is estimated to last until 2033 for OASI separately or 2034 for OASDI -- not as long as it should be, but long enough to be fixed, as it already was once before back in 1983.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 wasn't the trust fund added to the general budget during the administration of Bush the Second?